# angular js data binding not displaying

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

here is my controller:

```
  $scope.openReview = function(recipe_id){
  console.log(recipe_id);
  CommentList.getRecipeDetails(recipe_id);

     $scope.newComment.recipeID = recipe_id;
     CommentList.all($scope.newComment.recipeID).then(function(payload) {
     $scope.feedbackdata = payload;
     console.log(payload);
 });

}
```

my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Reviews" enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
<ion-content>
<div class="items item item-avatar" ng-repeat="comment in feedbackdata">
  <h2>{{comment.firstname}} {{comment.lastname}}</h2>
  <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to retrieve data.  My console already displays but it doesn't display anything in my view.

```
0: Object
    comment: "asdfgh"
    firstname: "Ana"
    lastname: "Luna"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    comment: "qwerty"
    firstname: "Andrea"
    lastname: "Swift"
```

---

Here are my additional codes

model

```
public function feedback_data($recipe_id)
{
    $this->db->select('feedback.comment,user.firstname,user.lastname');
    $this->db->from('feedback');
    $this->db->join('user','user.user_id = feedback.user_id');
    $this->db->where('feedback.recipe_id', $recipe_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

main

```
public function get_feedback_data()
{
    $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $feedback = $this->User_model->feedback_data($postdata);
    echo json_encode($feedback);
}
```

service

```
        all: function(recipe_id) {
      return $http.post("http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_feedback_data", recipe_id).then(function(result){
        return result.data;
      })
    },
```

Help me please.. please help me

Comment: any errors showing in console?

Comment: No errors..     nothing displays in my view

Comment: Need to see more of your code. Is your set up correct - html `ng-app`/`ng-controller`, `app.js` etc?

Comment: since your console displays correct data, i think there is something wrong with the view. can you show your index.html?

Comment: index.html or the view where the data display??

Comment: the complete view if possible. Its hard to debug with the view you have provided since  the binding is correct in that particular div.

Comment: since your log shows the data it has something to do with the view, which controller are you binding to the view , you are missing those parts, you should have something like <div ng-controller="myController">. i want to see those part. and the controllername?

Comment: its in my app.js .... where i set the controller to the specific view

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h2>{{comment.firstname}} {{comment.lastname}}</h2>
 <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
```

Just remove this line

{{comment.feedback_id}}

Because i think  feedback_id is not in the binded array

Comment: am i doing the right thing in declaring the ng-repeat??

Comment: ng-repeat  syntax is correct did you alert $scope.feedbackdata

Comment: but i need to display that image

Comment: the html code was also included above.. the second one

Comment: whole html code  just  try to check wheter it is working without html or not

Comment: <ion-view view-title="Reviews" enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
 <ion-content>
  <div class="items item item-avatar" ng-repeat="comment in feedbackdata">
      <h2>{{comment.firstname}} {{comment.lastname}}</h2>
      <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
  }
</ion-view>

Comment: does this $scope.feedbackdata retrun array or simple object?

Comment: and you didn't include controller name in the parent control

Comment: it is set in my app.js

Comment: change ng-repeat="comment in feedbackdata" to "comment1 in feedbackdata" and use the properties with comment1 just a try

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the data in the array of object form like `[{id:1,ima:gh.jpg},{id=2,ima:jh.jpg}]` in this form